# Is there a way on how to automatically add event to calendar based on external input?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, calendar

Is there really a way how can my android apps call user data from localstorage to the calendar (any type of calendar plugins will do)

The example story for my problem is like this: "The user fill in the form provided and then all the user input has been saved on the localstorage. Finally, when he/she go to the next scene which is the calendar part, the input that has been saved, will automatically inserted on the calendar based on the user date and time input."

I hope you understand my apps concept.
I'm stating "based on external input" means that, the user is not add event on the calendar itself but fill in some form as an input and later it will show on the calendar.

Is there a good term for this? and if the there is a way, how?

Comment: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'external source');` try this way

Comment: I think i know how this code works, but how to match my user date input with the calendar date? For example, my user date and time input is a string while i'm not really sure what type of variable used on the calendar.